# OpenDJ schema update and data update

Tags: opendj

What we are doing now is to modify(add/delete) ldap schema (OpenDJ) during runtime.

For example， our APP can DO below during runtime:

1. add a new attribute (ldap schema), say ns-gender. And add this new attribute into some person objectclass.
   Thus, all users can have this attribute.
2. suppose we have existing 1000 user entries in OpenDJ, and all of these users has such an attribute.
3. And our App wants to delete this attribute during runtime as well. Which means, we have to:
   a. iterate over all these existing 1000 users, delete the attribute from the user entry.
   b. then delete the ns-gender schema

I'm wondering if there's an easier way to achieve this ?

- Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no better or easier way.
Note that it is not a good practice to add and delete attributes definitions frequently with any LDAP directory service.